# Concatenate words separated by "_" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need help with the following problem:

My column in A2 in Excel has the value: `TB_PLACES_NAMES`

But I need to separate the "_" from the others words in the same column.

I've tried this function:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A2;2);MID(A2;4;5);MID(A2;10;4))
```

**Observation:**

Well, there's a rule that I have to follow, I can't delete the "_", because it marks how much words my table has [TB_PLACES_NAMES = 3 words -> So I must get the following information based on my table name **TB PLACES NAME** = TBPLACENAME <- This is what the text will look like].

But I don't know how to write a function that jumps to the other letter when it finds the "_".

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just remove underscores instead, e.g., `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","")`?

Comment: Well, there's a rule that I have to follow, I can't delete the underscore, because it marks how much words my table has [TB_PLACES_NAMES = 3 words -> So I must get the following information based on my table name TB PLACES NAME = TBPLACENAME <- This is what the text will look like].

But I don't know how to write a function that jumps to the other letter when it finds the "_".

Comment: SUBSTITUTE doesn't *delete* the underscore. It produces what you want in a different cell, leaving the original intact. The output is just like the CONCATENATE function you're seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following instead:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","")
```

This will return the contents of A2 but without the underscores.